# Generate XML with attributes from generic JSON

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson

I'm trying to write a generic JSON to XML converter and cannot figure out how to convert some JSON properties to XML attributes.

Let's say I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "data" : {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : {
      "value": "value2",
      "attribute#someattribute": "value3"
    }
  }
}
```

then I would like to obtain this:

```
<xml>
  <data>
    <key1>value1</key1>
    <key2 someattribute=value3>value2</key2>
  </data>
</xml>
```

I can change the convention to something else, but should be able to achieve something similar.

So far I'm converting the JSON to a Map<String, Object> and writing that to XML.

```java
    xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_1_1, true);

    final SimpleModule sm = new SimpleModule();

    sm.addKeySerializer(String.class, new JsonSerializer<String>() {
      @Override
      public void serialize(final String value, final JsonGenerator gen, final SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeFieldName(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11(value.trim()));
      }
    });
    xmlMapper.registerModule(sm);

    final OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    xmlMapper.writer().withRootName(rootElement).writeValue(os, map.get(rootElement));
```

I can hook into the serialize() method and intercept the writing from there, but it seems to write keys and values one-after-another. The ToXmlGenerator has a method called setNextIsAttribute() but I don't know how to hook into that.

Answer (score 1):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library has static method U.jsonToXml(json).

JSON

```
{
  "data" : {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : {
      "value": "value2",
      "attribute#someattribute": "value3"
    }
  }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <key1>value1</key1>
  <key2>
    <value>value2</value>
    <attribute__EM__someattribute>value3</attribute__EM__someattribute>
  </key2>
</data>
```